# How do I troubleshoot mounting my phone?

Tags: usb-connection-mode

❄️ I have a  Moto G6, running Android 9 (specifically PPSS29.118.15.11.2, Security Patch Level Oct 1,2019)❄️ and when I connect it via USB I have an option (under USB Preferences) to "Use USB for ... File Transfer" which is selected.

The "Use USB for" options that I see are these:

- File Transfer
- USB Tethering
- MIDI
- PTP
- No data transfer

With "File Transfer" selected, the phone appears as an external drive on my desktop (Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS) but I can't move anything on or off it and the mounted drive shows no directories and my desktop properties say that "Permissions could not be determined".

I installed `mtp-tools` as suggested in answer to [phone mounts as media device not usb storage](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/27283/phone-mounts-as-media-device-not-usb-storage) but that didn't change anything.

I'm not even sure what "MIDI" is for, but with MIDI selected, I don't even see my phone mounted as a drive.

If I select "Use USB for ... PTP" I can mount the DCIM and Pictures directories. I was able to drop an MP3 into my Pictures directory and then use the Files app to move it to the Music directory, but that's a poor substitute for actually mounting it and moving files back and forth. It does confirm that the issue isn't the cable (as in this 2013 question: [How do I mount my phone?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/45762/how-do-i-mount-my-phone))

I read through two questions that were solved by enabling USB Debugging: [How to get USB file transfer working on Oreo 8.1?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/197717/how-to-get-usb-file-transfer-working-on-oreo-8-1) and [Android Pie only showing two folders to Android File Transfer](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/204580/android-pie-only-showing-two-folders-to-android-file-transfer) but that didn't work for me. (Note, in 9.0 you have to find your Build in the System Settings and tap it 7 times to even access developer settings. From there you can enable USB Debugging).

Any new and different tips for mounting my Android 9.0 so I can transfer files to and from it?

Comment: If you have the PTP option you should also have the MPT one, don't you?. The latter is for accessing everything else but the DCIM folder.

Comment: I believe that the "File Transfer" option is MPT. But I updated to list the options that I see.

Comment: Maybe, maybe not... Any current Android should work with MTP/PTP (last time I saw the former method - mass storage device - available was in an old tablet running 4.4.4) but it's possible that for some weird reason Motorola decided to use it partially and enabled the old way as well, I don't know. Anyway, it should work as well in any desktop OS.

Comment: "File Transfer" is MTP which is handled by GVfs on Ubuntu. Make sure relevant packages are installed. Or you may mount it as drive using `mtpfs`. Another option to mount as drive is `adbfs` which uses `adb`. MTP has always been buggy, so better try not wasting time with it. Go with one of many other available options.

Comment: @IrfanLatif can you expand on those options? I just confirmed that `gvfs` is definitely installed, so that's not the issue.

Comment: "Permissions could not be determined" can be due to improper or missing `udev` rules. See this: https://askubuntu.com/q/87667/782461. MTP bugs and alternatives are already widely discussed topics. E.g. see this: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/209119/218526 and this: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/91900/218526